# Windows Game (4.0) Program Can't Find a File I Created?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Facing a lame issue. For some reason, my program can't seem to locate a file i made. I have this line of code:

```
 myCoolFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("TheFont/myFont.spritefont");
```

In my "Content" project i've created a folder called "TheFont" ... Within this folder, i've created a .spritefont file called "myFont"

why am i incapable of accessing it? what am i doing wrong here?

### EDIT:

If i put the entire path, it finds the file but says it can't open it :S why is this?

Comment: Does it also fail if you use backslash (\\) rather than forward slash (/) to separate the path components (using appropriate literal syntax to escape it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the file extension. The content pipeline compiles every file into "filename.xfb" and annotates the corresponding file type.

```
myCoolFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("TheFont/myFont");
```

Edit: Of course, the spritefont must be set to "Compile" in tyour project. If you have a .spritefont in the compiled version, *you're compiling it wrong*.

Comment: Thanks... i guess that was the issue, haven't checked it out yet

Comment: I was pretty sure it was the issue, and it is verified now. I don't just blindly accept answers at random... you'll notice that if you look at the other Questions i've posted... Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry I was so rude. And thanks for the reply and confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a reference to your content project in your main one. You probably need to set the content root to the name of the content project, usually just 'content'. When you load your font don't include the .spritefont extension. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep this in mind when i look back at the program again. Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the need to use a full-path specification for the file by setting the `CurrentDirectory` property

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Full-Path-To-Application\");
```

As for the reading issue - try checking the Security settings for the file, since you created it manually - it probably has some restrictions on it as par your user.

Comment: where would i have to go to check the security settings for the file? I don't think i've ever had to do this before when creating a file...

Comment: @BlueMonster right click on the file->Properties and go to the Security tab, make sure 'Everyone' has full-control on it, also check that it's not being locked by another process (maybe you opened it once and forgot to close it using your Text editor or anything alike)

Comment: Hmm... there is no tab called "Security" or anything even similar. The only things i see include: Asset Name, Build Action, Content Importer, Content Processor, Copy to Output Directory, File Name, Full Path.

Comment: @BlueMonster - I'm referring to WINDOWS security options.. not VS. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419

Comment: Hmm, everything here is fine. All it is, is a sprite file. I'm having the same issue with just reading a textfile i open specifically in this project - not in any other project i create.

Answer (score 0):

I had a great amount of trouble with this.

I fixed it by chosen the property of the file you are trying to load, and change the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if Newer", since the default value is "Do Not Copy".

Hope it can help someone.